# iPhone :: Objective-C - AddSubview in my initial UIViewController ViewDidAppear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Hihi all,

This could very well be a silly question. I would like to navigate to my "Login View" upon the launching of my application. My current tries:

1. In my first UIViewController's viewDidAppear method, perform a [self presentModalViewController:LoginView animated:YES], this works, but the screen shows my main UIView first, then slide my LoginView from bottom to top. I can't find a way to perform it without the animation.
2. In my first UIViewController's viewDidAppear method, perform a [self.view addSubview:LoginView.view], it ends up with exc_bad_access error.

Basically, my requirement is to perform certain checks upon starting of the application, if a login is required, the application shall display the LoginView, otherwise, it should stay as my main UIView.

Please advice what is the best way of achieving this, instead of the above two silly methods. Thanks in advance!

:)

Comment: The crashes you're having make it sound like there's an issue with the way you're creating your login view controller object.  Perhaps you could show us some more code related to that?

Comment: I have followed Roshit's solution to move my checking routine to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions at my application delegate and it works like a charm. Thanks for your suggestion! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying it in `**- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {**`

example :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    LoginViewController *aLoginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:aLoginViewController animated:NO];
    [aLoginViewController release];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: this should have worked... :( Is it possible for you to share snippets of your code.

Comment: My bad, after crashing continuously for awhile, I have made a silly mistake before trying out this solution. It works finally after clearing the mistake. Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

your 1st step is a good way..
but to stop animation, its very simple. Set animated to NO.

[self presentModalViewController:aLoginViewController animated:NO];

once ur done with ur validation, just dismiss this aLoginViewController.

Comment: if I set the animated to NO, my LoginView is not being shown at all. It just stays at my main UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `-viewDidAppear`, it sounds like you want to use `-viewWillAppear:`, which will allow you to present your login controller before the initial view is displayed.

`-presentModalViewController:animated` is the right method to display your login controller's view.

Comment: Have just tried it, for viewWillAppear, both addSubview and presentModalViewController do not work. :(